# model relationship design for Blog app in Wagtail site

Tags: wagtail

Below models.py to build a blog in wagtail site is from [this post](https://www.accordbox.com/blog/add-blog-models-wagtail/).

```
class BlogPage(Page):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True,)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [FieldPanel("description", classname="full")]


class PostPage(Page):
    header_image = models.ForeignKey(
        "wagtailimages.Image",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name="+",
    )

    tags = ClusterTaggableManager(through="blog.PostPageTag", blank=True)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        ImageChooserPanel("header_image"),
        InlinePanel("categories", label="category"),
        FieldPanel("tags"),
    ]


class PostPageBlogCategory(models.Model):
    page = ParentalKey(
        "blog.PostPage", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="categories"
    )
    blog_category = models.ForeignKey(
        "blog.BlogCategory", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="post_pages"
    )

    panels = [
        SnippetChooserPanel("blog_category"),
    ]

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("page", "blog_category")


@register_snippet
class BlogCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=80)

    panels = [
        FieldPanel("name"),
        FieldPanel("slug"),
    ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Category"
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"


class PostPageTag(TaggedItemBase):
    content_object = ParentalKey("PostPage", related_name="post_tags")


@register_snippet
class Tag(TaggitTag):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

I am wondering, what are the major reasons to introduce extra Intermediary model **(class PostPageBlogCategory(models.Model): & class PostPageTag(TaggedItemBase):)** to link **PostPage** to **Category & Tag**?
Why not just simply use **ParentalForeignkey** or **ParentalManyToManyKey** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that Django's `ManyToManyField` has some limitations in how the relationship needs to be built when models on either end to not yet exist, adding an 'intermediary model' helps to work around this.

### Longer Answer

As with anything in software, there are multiple ways to do something and each has its own pros & cons. Django's built in field is simple and lets you do lots of powerful things to represent relational data but that simplicity comes with some reduced flexibility in how these relationships are managed.

One of the main goals of the Wagtail CMS Admin interface is the ability to work as though the data has been created (including relationships) before actually clicking 'save'. While this may seem simple at first glance, getting to that point requires a bit of nuance under the hood once you start to consider relational data.

- Wagtail comes built in with a very powerful library called [`django-modelcluster`](https://github.com/wagtail/django-modelcluster) which has been purpose built for many of the cases where you want to work with relational data without having all the bits in the DB first.
- Each Wagtail `Page` actually inherits the `modelcluster.models.ClusterableModel`, which is why some of the features in the blog post seem to work in the editor, even when the DB entries have not yet been saved.
- On the [blog post](https://www.accordbox.com/blog/add-blog-models-wagtail/)  you linked, there is a section towards the end with the heading ['ParentalKey'](https://www.accordbox.com/blog/add-blog-models-wagtail/#parentalkey) that further explains this nuance and how just using Django's basic approach has some draw backs.
- On the [Django docs for many-to-many relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/), have  a read through and note that each individual model instance must be in the database first and only then can you 'link' the two instances with a second update on each.

Comment: Much appreciate your detailed explanation, which is quite insightful and helpful. However, my major question is why we introduce extra Intermediary model (`class PostPageBlogCategory(models.Model):` & `class PostPageTag(TaggedItemBase):`) to link `PostPage` to `Category & Tag` ? Hence I further edited my post (change `foreignkey` to `ParentalForeignKey`) as previous version was a bit misleading.  Appreciate if you can further provide insightful answers.

Comment: I guess I already find the answer in [this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships). In this link, it indicates, intermediary model is introduced when we want to store more details about the `relationship` (such as date_of_creation, reason_for_creation etc). In my original question, the reason for introducing intermediary model is to bring in `panels = [SnippetChooserPanel("blog_category"),]` and `unique_together = ("page", "blog_category")` ?